# Loop over content file in puppet

Tags: puppet

How can I iterate over lines in a file with puppet?
I'm trying to do somwthing like this in my manifest:

```
$tables = file('/home/myhome/tables')

$tables.each |String $table| {
    exec {"/usr/bin/${binary}":
        command => "/bin/echo '${table}'",
    }
}
```

And I got the error:

Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find any files from /home/rraposo/tables (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/11_fhc/alfresco-para-testes.pp, line: 92, column: 11) on node fhc-prod-pt-alfresco-para-testes-01

My file have lines like this:

act_evt_log
act_evt_log_log_nr__seq
act_ge_bytearray
act_ge_property
act_hi_actinst
act_hi_attachment
act_hi_comment
act_hi_detail
act_hi_identitylink

Comment: Puppet functions, such as `file()`, run during catalog building, and therefore on the server.  And to the extent that they access external resources, they do it with the privileges of the puppetserver process.  Either or both of these could prevent Puppet from reading your file.  Additionally, even if you read the file successfully, `file()` returns the contents as a (single) string.  You would need to split it into lines separately to iterate over those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that your code lives on a Puppet server and the /home/myhome/tables file is on the target node, so the Puppet agent run lifecycle is;

1. The agent sends facts to the Puppet server, you can see exactly what facts by running `facter` on the command line. The only thing the Puppet server knows about the node are the facts sent by the agent.
2. The Puppet server compiles the catalog, this is the point where your lambda is run.
3. The compiled catalog is sent back to the node.
4. The agent receives the catalog and corrects any deviation from the catalog.

The fix for this is to somehow get the contents of that file included in the facts that are sent up to the Puppet server. You can do this using external facts https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/custom_facts.html#external-facts.

You could have Puppet deploy a file `/etc/facter/facts.d/tables.sh` and inside that file you have something like;

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tables=($(grep act_ /home/myhome/tables))
echo "tables=${tables[*]}"
```

That will include a fact called tables which will contain an array that lists the contents of that file that your lambda should be able to work with.

This isn't a great way to use Puppet though, what we really want is to specify in code what we want the node to look like and then apply that. Reading a config file from a node effectively allows it to determine its own configuration. A preferable solution would be to specify that list in hiera https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.5/hiera_intro.html take a look at the quick start guide here https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.5/hiera_quick.html.